# Error: jslint gives me error here for bad looping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jslint

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  datatype: 'json',
  url: '/CreateUser',
  data: data
  cache: false
}).success(function(data) { //Error:jslint gives me error here for bad looping
  console.log(data.message);
}).error(function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

I use **jslint** package in **Atom** Editor, where I pass callback response it gives me error **Error:jslint gives me error here for bad looping** what is this?
Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two `}` in the success callback.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    datatype:'json',
    url: '/CreateUser',
    data:data
    cache: false
}).success(function (data){
    console.log(data.message);
}).error(function (error){
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: .success(function (data){
    console.log(data.message); // error
}) gives me error  i don't know what is that? but my code works perfectly

Comment: @Spartan I'm not sure what you are asking in your first comment.

Comment: still callback function gives me warning

Comment: Is it a different error message or the same? If you could, would you please provide the error message *exactly* as it reads from the linter.